# Проблема переименование переменной с JavaParser

Tags: java, парсер

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с проблемой при работе с **JavaParser**.

Имеется код:

```
private void editLocalField() throws IOException {
    CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(classFile.getFile());
    new EditLocalFieldVisitor().visit(cu, null);
    System.out.println(cu);
    classFile.writeFile(cu.toString());
}

private class EditLocalFieldVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter<Void> {
    @Override
    public void visit(FieldDeclaration n, Void arg) {
        if(n.getVariable(0).getName().asString().equals(oldFieldName)){
            n.getVariable(0).setName(newFieldName);
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно в файле **classFile.getFile()** хранится код:

```
public class Test extends AbstractProcessCommand {

/*comment*/
private String test;}
```

В этом случае все работает и поле меняет свое имя. Но если код в файле:

```
public class Test extends AbstractProcessCommand {

/*comment*/
private String test;

test = "some Text";}
```

То здесь уже выскакивает ошибка:

```
Caused by: com.github.javaparser.ParseProblemException: (line 13,col 2) Parse error. Found "=", expected one of  "enum" "exports" "module" "open" "opens" "provides" "requires" "strictfp" "to" "transitive" "uses" "with" <IDENTIFIER>
```

Т.е. **javaParser** не может обработать присвоение.
Как быть? По сути необходимо в данном контексте поменять имя поля везде, где оно встречается в классе. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: во втором случае у вас java-код неправильный.

Comment: Точно! вот это я прогледел такую глупую ошибку....Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: Но, к сожалению, переименование происходит не по всему классу. Есть ли какой-нибудь метод, чтобы сделать что-то вроде рефакторинга?